# Trouble while building Caffe

Tags: python, cuda, caffe

Well, I'm trying to build Caffe. I did `make all` and then this error

```
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:625: recipe for target '.build_release/tools/upgrade_solver_proto_text.bin' failed
```

I start with this [Guide](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Ubuntu-16.04-or-15.10-Installation-Guide)

Error occured after this:

```
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNormRel_L2_16u_C1R'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `ippicviResizeCubic_16u_C4R'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `ippicviNorm_L2_16u_C3R'
```

OS: Ubuntu 16.04

I don't have ideas about that. Any help?

Comment: How did you download `Caffe`?

Comment: Could you please add on which step the error occured? Please click [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/924094/edit) below your question and add the information.

Comment: He said that the error occured when he ran `make all` .

Comment: Well, I downloaded Caffe from repository with git clone

Comment: Try downloading from [here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/releases/tag/1.0). It is said to be a stable release

Comment: @yamboy1 downloaded that stable release and still the same error.

Comment: Have a look at these instructions http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/install_apt.html

Comment: When I was started I used to follow these instuctions, but still the same issue.